# Which permissions to uncheck to disable a profile from creating dashboards and report

Tags: reporting, permissions, profile, dashboard

I have a the following requirements:

1. profile A which does not create any reports and dashboards, and
   other users cannot share with this profile, even if they do share
   this profile cannot read those shared with it.
2. profile B which does not create any reports and dashboards, but
   other users can share with this profile, and the profile can see
   those shared with it.
3. profile C which does not create any reports and dashboards, but view
   all reports and dashboard.

I am not sure which combinations of profile permissions I need in order to fulfill the above requirements.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take our [Tour](/tour), read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask), and then edit your question to _show the community what have you tried and where you are stuck_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> profile A which does not create any reports and dashboards, and other users cannot share with this profile, even if they do share this profile cannot read those shared with it.

- Reports Tab: hidden
- Dashboards Tab: hidden
- Run Reports: false
- Create and Customize  Dashboards: false
- Create and Customize Reports: false
- View My Team's Dashboards: false

Note that technically reports and dashboards can still be shared to this profile, but they can't view reports or dashboards, so it's the same difference.

> profile B which does not create any reports and dashboards, but other users can share with this profile, and the profile can see those shared with it.

- Reports Tab: shown
- Dashboards Tab: shown
- Run Reports: true
- Create and Customize Reports: false
- Create and Customize Dashboards: false
- View My Team's Dashboards: true

> profile C which does not create any reports and dashboards, but view all reports and dashboard.

Not possible. You would need to give them administrative access to reports and dashboards to view *all* reports and dashboards, and at that point, they would also be able to edit and delete those items as well. There's no permission for "view all dashboards and reports" that does not also include the right to manage those items.

Comment: in addition to Create and Customize Reports there is also Create and Customize Dashboards, this should be false also right?

Comment: @nSv23 Right. I overlooked that one.